# uwsgi + python + nginx + willy nilly file execution

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi on Nginx to run some Python code.

I'd like to bind uwsgi to a directory and make it render any .py file that I call from the server in the browser. I'm thinking like PHP, here (/index.php executes that file, /login.php executes that file).

Is this a possibility? Or am I only able to explicitly specify a single module/app/file in uwsgi?

Here is my init syntax:

```
/opt/uwsgi/uwsgi -s 127.0.0.1:9001 -M 4 -t 30 -A 4 -p 4 -d /var/log/uwsgi.log --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi.pid --pythonpath /srv/www
```

I thought that would allow `/srv/www` to act as the folder where any .py files are executed.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  DONT_NEED_THIS;

    access_log  /srv/www/logs/access.log;
    error_log   /srv/www/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        root  /srv/www;

        # added lines    
        include        uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9001;

    }
```

As it stands, when I try to call web root (ie www.site.com/) I get a:

```
wsgi application not found
```

With the following index.py file:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WSGI is not like PHP. You can't just point uwsgi to a directory with a bunch of .py files. In fact, never, ever make your python modules available in a public directory, accessible from the server. You need to hook uwsgi up to a WSGI application, preferably a framework. Read more about WSGI [here](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2007/5/21/getting-started-with-wsgi/). Check out [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) which is small, simple WSGI framework. It has great docs, and it's easy to get started with. There are actually tons of great web frameworks for Python though, so feel free to look around :)

Comment: Forgive me for being a noob... is Python, in general, like PHP (i.e. per file execution)? Or is the typical standard a single-file portal to an application framework?

Comment: No it's not like PHP in general, although you can do CGI stuff. It's recommended and best to use WSGI, which is essentially a  definition of the interaction between web applications and web servers. Python has a rich ecosystem of WSGI servers and frameworks, which greatly simplifies application development, deployment, aids interoperability, etc, etc. It's the only way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read this thread:

http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2011-March/001657.html